# SOAP authentication with PHP WSDL

Tags: php, authentication, soap, wsdl

I have looked at several related topics, but none solved my wsdl/soap/php issue.

My header looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://"> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Header> 
        <ns:authentication> 
            <username>username</username> 
            <password>password</password> 
        </ns:authentication> 
    </SOAP-ENV:Header> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am not able to succesfully connect. I've tried sample codes but none of them worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Additional authentication info:

```
<xsd:complexType>
           <xsd:all>
              <xsd:element name="username" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                 <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Username for authenticatie</xsd:documentation>
                 </xsd:annotation>
                 <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                       <xsd:maxLength value="4000"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                 </xsd:simpleType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="password" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                 <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Password for authentication</xsd:documentation>
                 </xsd:annotation>
                 <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                       <xsd:maxLength value="4000"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                 </xsd:simpleType>
              </xsd:element>
           </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

A full working request looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:zone="http://">
   <soapenv:Header>
       <zone:authentication>
          <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
          <username>myusername</username>
          <password>mypassword</password>
       </zone:authentication>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <zone:searchSubscriptionRequest>
          <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
          <requestTag>test</requestTag>
          <zipcode>000 AB</zipcode>
       </zone:searchSubscriptionRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: What is the service authentication type?

Comment: I´ve added some information, maybe you can see what type of authentication it is based on that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not using standard `<SOAP-ENV:Header>` authentication, instead username and password are regular variables inside `<SOAP-ENV:Body>`.

The snippet is out of context, so I can't tell you how to set them, but you can use some WSDL to PHP code generator to get PHP classes for you to discover.

Comment: I've added a working request from SoapUI. Maybe this makes it more clear? Thank you, I will look into a generator.